# Implementing Rails 3 template handlers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

It appears there's not much documentation on Rails template handlers. There's the included handlers, like RJS, ERB, and Builder, which offer some assistance.

I'm trying to implement my own, and I've succeeded, albeit with a bit of weird code, or possibly there's something I don't quite understand.

```
class MyHandler < ActionView::Template::Handler
  def call(template)
    template.source.inspect
  end
end
```

So what's weird is that I have to call `inspect`, otherwise Rails will try to eval the string as Ruby code.

I was under the impression that that's what `include ActionView::...::Compilable` did (which I'm not including in my code).

Now, if I make my template "compilable" (by using the `include...` statement), it still looks for the `call` method instead of the `compile` method.

So could anyone explain to me a bit more about how this works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) and [temple](https://github.com/judofyr/temple), I have learnt a lot about template engines reading their code.

Answer (score 4):

I've just been going through this problem myself. Basically rails expects the renderer's `.call` method to return ruby code that will render your template. It then [dynamically generates a method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb#L262) which runs this code, and injects it into a module.

The module has all of the url/application helpers included, which means they're in scope for the template.

So, in answer to your question the solution is for `.call` to return some ruby code that outputs your rendered template as a string, or for it to render ruby code that invokes your template engine.